# How can I fix this java?

Tags: java, while-loop

I am working on this program with these instructions:

Bus Passengers: Write a program that is to be used to count how many passengers are travelling on
buses that pass a particular bus stop in a given hour. It should use a while loop to repeatedly ask the user to give the number of passengers on the bus that just passed. It should stop when the special code X is entered as the number of passengers. It should then give the number of buses and the total number of passengers counted in that hour. For example, one run might be as follows.

```
How many passengers were on the bus? 2
How many passengers were on the bus? 5
How many passengers were on the bus? 10
How many passengers were on the bus? 3
How many passengers were on the bus? 12
How many passengers were on the bus? 1
How many passengers were on the bus? 0
How many passengers were on the bus? X

There were a total of 33 passengers on 7 buses.
```

I am trying to fix an error:

Comment: You need to pass userInput and a to your busInformation method when calling it. Please look at Java syntax

Comment: You specify the parameters and return value of a method for a *REASON*.  The parameters a method is called with *MUST MATCH* the parameters in your declaration!  You're calling "busInformation()" like this: `busInformation();`  You're missing `String userInput` and ` int a`.  Q: Why does it matter?  A: Read about [strongly typed languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing)

Comment: Creating a new scanner every time to get a single input is about as inefficient as you can get. Not to mention the fact that you are parsing the `nextLine()` without doing anything doesn't improve the situation either.

Comment: Yes, you should just have one Scanner on System.in, and pass it as a parameter (or store it as an instance variable).

Comment: I would recommend just asking your Java teacher for help. Answering this question won't really help you learn anything other than bad habits.

Comment: @Spectric it is worse than inefficient.  Under some circumstances it can lead to incorrect behavior.

Comment: @StephenC Ha! You would have thought he would have been so generous to close it!

Comment: No ... not closing it is not the fundamental problem here.  The real problem is that one `Scanner` may read ahead (and therefore consume) characters that should be read by another `Scanner`.  Leads to lost input.

Comment: @StephenC The scanners use the same underlying stream, so they don't skip data.

Comment: @NomadMaker - 1) Scanners have internal buffering; e.g. to implement the `hashNext` methods.  2) There may be buffering in the underlying streams.  So if you (for example) repeatedly wrapped `System.in` in a `BufferedInputStream` (for ... reasons) read-ahead could be consumed in the `BIS` buffers.

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your particular technical issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few points to note:-

1. You don't need System.exit()
2. In java variables are only accessible inside their scope i.e. the region they are created in.

I tried to rewrite code as following:-

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bus {
    int busCount =0;
    int passengerCount =0;
    Scanner scanner= new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Bus bus = new Bus();
        bus.getResults();
    }

    private void addBusAndPassenger(String input){
        try{
            int a = Integer.parseInt(input);
            busCount = busCount + 1;
            passengerCount = passengerCount + a;
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
            System.out.println("Please provide integer or X as input");
        }
    }

    private void getResults(){
        String a =null;
        while (!("X".equals(a))){
            System.out.print("How many passengers were on the bus? ");
            a = scanner.nextLine();
            if("X".equals(a))
                break;

            addBusAndPassenger(a);
        }
        System.out.println("There were a total of " + passengerCount + " passengers on " + busCount + " buses.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things here. Other people pointed this out, but you need to pass parameters to your method. The method signature is there for a reason - your method calls must match the method signature you define.

Also, `busInformation` is supposed to return an `int`, but it returns nothing.

Also, this line:

```
Integer.parseInt(a);
```

does nothing - you throw away the result immediately. It won't modify the string in place or anything like that. (Well, I suppose that it'll throw an exception if they enter something other than an integer, but that doesn't seem to be what you're trying to do with this line).

At an absolute minimum, you should change the return type of your method to `int` and the change this line to `return Integer.parseInt(a);`.

(You also shouldn't be creating a new scanner every time like this - you should just re-use the same one).

Comment: Nice job in summarizing multiple different rants into one! +1